# FlatList inside useMemo, initalNumToRender issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-usememo

I have a `FlatList` inside `useMemo` as follows

```
    const content = useMemo<JSX.Element>(
        () =>
            isLoading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : !alerts.length ? (
                <View style={styles.noAlertsContainer}>
                    <NoAlertsIcon width={scaleHeight(182)} height={scaleHeight(201)} />
                    <Text numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit style={styles.noAlertsText}>
                        {i18n.t('alerts-empty')}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <FlatList
                    initialNumToRender={9}
                    getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
                    bounces={false}
                    data={alerts}
                    keyExtractor={it => it.id}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                />
            ),
        [isLoading]
    )
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Header title={i18n.t('drawer-alerts')} onBackPress={navBack} renderEndElement={headerEndElement} />
            <View style={styles.divider} />
            {content}
        </Fragment>
    )
```

The issue is that after adding the `initalNumToRender` prop, only that number of items rendered (scrolling down won't render more items, will just have blank space accords the number of supposed items). Removing it, either taking this `content` block directly to the `return` part (without `useMemo`) fix the issue.
Any idea about the best thing to do? don't want to let go of `useMemo` or `initalNumToRender`...

What I found really weird as well, is according to the docs, `InitalNumToRender` default is `10`, but not specifying this prop won't cause the list to stack at 10 items

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At least you are missing to add dependencies in your useMemo hook. getItemLayout, renderItem.

Comment: indeed adding `renderItem` to the dependecy array fixed it. Thanks! though it still super weird as the function `renderItem` isn't changing or causing rerender

Comment: I am not sure because I don't know how `renderItem` function looks, but we should add dependencies correctly in hooks such as `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`. Otherwise, we may get the unexpected results. Anyway, glad to hear you get the result.